# How to create containerized Spring Boot App on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose, raspberry-pi4

#### What am I wanting to do?

I want to convert to run my ***containerized of Spring-Boot's app*** which is can run on amd64 systems, on Raspberry Pi 4's Docker. How can I fix the my problem?

#### What's the running OS on Raspberry Pi?

I've installed ***Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS for arm64 architectures*** using via ***Raspberry Pi Imager v1.6.1*** on ***Raspberry Pi 4***.

---

#### What are the steps I have done to fix the problem?(problem is still continue)

In default version does not work on my ***Raspberry Pi.*** Thus, I've tried some couple of things at below.

I changed row of "FROM" from ***[openjdk:15-jdk-slim](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk)*** to ***[arm64v8/openjdk:17](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/openjdk/)*** at my ***dockerfile*** as you can see:

```
FROM arm64v8/openjdk:17
COPY . /projects/red-dir
WORKDIR /projects/red-dir
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /projects/red-dir/my_red_app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/projects/red-dir/my_red_app.jar"]
```

Afterwards, I've built and pushed my app using with ***Maven*** and ***Docker***:

```
$ ./mvnw clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true && java -jar target/my_red_app.jar
$ docker build -t user/my_red_app:v1.0.0 .
```

Then, My app's depend on a MongoDB, so I changed this ***image*** from ***[mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)*** to ***[arm64v8/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/mongo/)*** on ***docker-compose.yml*** as you can see at below:

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongodb:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: arm64v8/mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
        networks:
            - shared-net
    colour_app:
        container_name: my_red_app
        image: user/my_red_app
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 7070:7070
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        networks:
            - shared-net
networks:
    shared-net:
        driver: bridge
```

---

#### Things that work and things that don't work

***MongoDB*** is running. I can reach using via ***MongoDBCompass***, but my ***Spring-Boot app*** doesn't work. In `docker-compose up` command, I've encountered an output like this:

```
...
...
colour_app    | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
colour_app    | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
colour_app    | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
colour_app    | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Let me know what things I didn't catch. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem and tried to create simple guide for ones who are encountered this problem.

#### BUILD FOR OTHER OS (multi-architecture / buildx command)

1. Turn On "experimental" feature's on Docker Settings.

   - ***For Linux OS***:

     1. `sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json`
     2. Add below content to it:

        ```json
        {
          "experimental": true
        }
        ```
   - ***For Win10 OS / MAC OS***:

     1. Open **Docker Desktop** application.
     2. Go to Settings.
     3. Select ***Docker Engine*** Tab on the left-side.
     4. Find `"experimental": false`.
     5. Change it to `"experimental": true`.
2. Restart Docker.
3. Create multi-architecture os. (***Important**: The **image** you are using should contain the **OS** you want to create it*)

   - Creating a just **SINGLE OS** :

     1. You can use load or push commands.

        - `--load` means that docker saves it to local disk:

          ```
          docker buildx build --load --platform linux/arm64 -t <dockerhub_username>/<repository_name>:<tag_name> .
          ```
        - `--push` means that docker doesn't save it to local disk but save it to cloud (docker hub):

          ```
          docker buildx build --push --platform linux/arm64 -t <dockerhub_username>/<repository_name>:<tag_name> .
          ```
        - `--load` and `--push` can not be set together.
   - Creating a **MANY OS** :

     2. You can just use push command with many OS.

        - `--push` means that docker doesn't save it to local disk but save it to cloud (docker hub):

          ```
          docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le -t <dockerhub_username>/<repository_name>:<tag_name> .
          ```